# Converting from file_get_contents to wp_remote_get

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm having some trouble converting this function from file_get_contents to wp_remote_get and I was hoping for some insight. This seems like I'm so close. Below are two cases, my original which works using file_get_contents, and the second which does the same thing but uses wp_remote_get and doesn't work. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm screwing up?

```
    case 'one':
        $url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd";
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
        $price = $json["last_price"];
        return $price;
        break;
    case 'two':
        $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd' );
    if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        return false;
    }
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
        $data = json_decode( $body );
        if( ! empty( $data ) ) {

            foreach( $data['last_price'] as $price ) {
                return $price;
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Did you print out all those variables from $request down to see what's in them ?

Comment: 'return $data' seems to break the site. No other PHP elements will load.

Comment: Not return, echo for variables and print_r() or var_dump() for arrays. Debugging is your friend. If the content of the variables and arrays is not what you expect it to be, then you find out why. First find out what.

Comment: Using print_r( $data ) gives me "stdClass Object ( [mid] => 0.000126245 [bid] => 0.000126 [ask] => 0.00012649 [last_price] => 0.00012649 [low] => 0.00009097 [high] => 0.00016183 [volume] => 32064835.81619025 [timestamp] => 1504582363.108115698 )"
but using print_r( $data['last_price'] ) seems to break the script and is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I view the decoded json, if looks like `$data['last_price']` is not an array.  So maybe what you want is:

This:

```
foreach( $data['last_price'] as $price ) {
     return $price;
}
```

Could just be:

```
return $data['last_price'];
```

Because the returned json object is just one array of what looks to be financial data.  That is also how you have it in your first example.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that it seems to break the script and nothing loads.

Comment: To be more exact, a 500 error shows up in the console.

Comment: Actually, this worked! I just needed to add true to json_decode. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

your `print_r( $data )` gives your "stdClass Object" but you are using

```
print_r( $data['last_price'] );
```

it gives you nothing.
so for getting object try

```
$test=$data->last_price;
print_r($test);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This does not solve the issue in the question, it is more suited to a comment. Please only add answers to questions if they address the actual problem, and can provide an alternative way of addressing the issue that is not already covered in the other answers provided.